# How can I disable Sundays in an AngularJS datepicker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm doing a web app with ruby on rails and Bootstrap UI for AngularJS. Have been trying for a while to disable picking any Sunday with the angular datepicker. Basically, I want the user to be available to pick a date from Monday to Saturday and not Sundays. Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have something like:

```
// Disable sundays
$scope.disabled = function(date, mode) {
    return ( mode === 'day' && ( date.getDay() === 0) );
};
```

And then in your datepicker:

```
<datepicker ng-model="dt" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" />
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/SpQzRMRSt2K8gWphjTiN?p=preview

Comment: Dave beat me to it, but here's the plunker I wrote:  http://plnkr.co/edit/FMoFlegBEZgFF32lBmbN?p=preview